# My project gives me the error in console -error from the source that it has created

Tags: html, react-router, gatsby

When I start my site, it gives the error (different) from the source that I don’t create.

Like:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

or

> GET https://gatsby-coffee-project-first.netlify.com/null net::ERR_ABORTED 404

or

> Syntax error like, missed tag '<' in null.

I find it, `<script src='null'></script>`, in my index.html. I try to delete it, but when I start `gatsby develop` it has created it anyway.

Try to write, like this `<script src='/null.js'></script>`, but like I said it overwrites it, anyway....